# i got and error while transfering code from pycharm to replit

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, replit

I have this piece of code i wrote in pycharm which which i want to transfer to replit so i could run it through my phone but i got an error which i cant understand how to solve

the code i tried is in this link cuz it wouldnt let me paste it here for some reason : https://replit.com/@milshteinnoam/kahoot-1

in pycharm this code works perfectly, it adds players with random number names to a kahoot
but in replit i get this error :   `Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/runner/kahoot-1/main.py", line 15, in <module>     driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)   File "/home/runner/kahoot-1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__     super().__init__(   File "/home/runner/kahoot-1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__     self.service.start()   File "/home/runner/kahoot-1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start     self.assert_process_still_running()   File "/home/runner/kahoot-1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 115, in assert_process_still_running     raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}") selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/runner/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/121.0.6167.85/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127`
if someone could tell me whats the problem and how to fix it it would be great
thx